# Centering three divs in twitter bootstrap footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I am new to this and I am trying to center three divs within bootstraps footer but they seem to be centered to the left. I am going off the Twitter Bootstrap framework and still learning the ropes so please let me know if there is anything I left out. Thank you!

HTML

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
    <div class="container narrow row-fluid">

      <div class="span3">
          <h3>Contact Us!</h3>
            <p>Have a question or comment? We can help you!</p>
            <br>by phone: 555-555-5555 
            <br>by mail: info@website.com
            <br>or by our: <a href="contact.htm">Contact Page</a>
      </div>


     <div class="span3">
        <a class="brand" href="index.htm"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="South Shore   Bicycle and Fitness" align="middle"> </a>
     </div>

      <div class="span3">
           <h3>Newsletter</h3>
          <p>Subscribe to our newsletter and get the latest news!</p>
          <form action="php/mail.php" id="subscribe-form" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
         </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </footer>
```

CSS

```
.modal-footer { padding: 14px 15px 15px;
margin-bottom: 0;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
*zoom: 1;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-footer:before, .modal-footer:after {
display: table;
content: "";
vertical-align: middle
}

.modal-footer:after {
clear: both;
vertical-align: middle
}

.modal-footer .btn {
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-bottom: 0;
vertical-align: middle
}

.span3 {
 width: 166px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin: 0 auto; to center elements.  Try adding this rule to your CSS:

```
.span3{
   margin: 0 auto
}
```

Then, also give one of the divs that contain the span3's a width:

```
.container{
   width: 515px /* The actual width may need to be higher or lower than this */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however itt still appears to be left centered.